# How to Invoke itemClick on a ListView?

Tags: uwp

I have a Listview and the ListView_OnItemClick event to handle the itemclick in the code behind. Now I want to invoke the itemclick programmatically on a certain index. How to do that?

I searched, could not find anything either in the ListViewBase.ItemClick Event documentation or in the Selector.SelectedItem Property documentation.

Comment: Why do you want to fire the click event programmatically? There might be another approach to do what you want.

Comment: I want to set a shortcut for the user to simulate a click on the list view for the selected index and for a particular index.

Comment: You could not simulate a click in the code behind. If you want, you could directly call the itemClick event in the code-behind, but there is no click effect in the UI layout.

Comment: Thank you, If this is the final answer, I accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, you could not simulate a click in the code behind. If you want, you could directly call the itemClick event in the code-behind to do the logic process, but there is no click effect in the UI layout.